# teamcity 'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cucumber, teamcity

I have the following command line:

```
cucumber "QA\Regression.Tests\features"
```

which I've successfully run on the server hosting TeamCity.

However, when I add the above as a build step in TeamCity to run, I get the following:

> teamcity 'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command

Can anyone help with resolving this issue?

Comment: the build step is executed on a build agent, which can be other than hosting server. Is there a cucumber available on TC Agent?

Comment: @Nikita - It's all on the same physical server.

Comment: Try checking the environment in wich build agent works. The simpliest thing to do - use "echo $PATH" in commandline

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov: Here is what I get for path Path=C:\Ruby192\bin;. I then looked in that folder and cucumber is there.